# Graphics Glitch or Modern Art?

Tags: graphics

I was trying to draw a simple surface and ended up with some modern art... if we start with a surface defined by a Gaussian shape and plot it, all looks well:

```
surf = GaussianMatrix[{100, 10}];
ListPlot3D[surf]
```

[image]

But if I try to plot the closely related 1-surf, some weird things happen:

```
ListPlot3D[1 - surf]
```

[image]

Rotating the image with my mouse gives:

[image]

I guess I'm wondering if there is something strange/iodiosyncratic about my setup or if this is generic...

Comment: What does `surf` look like if you give the vertical a range of 0 to 1? Maybe you can gather something from that?

Comment: It's modern art for sure. Setting `PlotRange -> Full` resolves the issue, so I think the problem lies in the code that selects the plot range automatically. There's something with the value range that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have too many `1.`'s, I guess, and the automatic plot range is too small.

```
ListPlot3D[1 - surf, PlotRange -> 1 - MinMax[surf]]
```

[image]

More than half of the entries of `1 - surf` are `1.`:

```
1 - surf;
Count[Flatten@%, 1.]
Length@Flatten@%%
(*
  21060
  40401
*)
```