# Strange behaviour with EllipticTheta functions

Tags: plotting, special-functions, numerical-value

For some time I have been using `EllipticTheta[3,-,-]` functions, and to me it seems that Mathematica is really not handling them in the best way. Below are two of the instances I have faced so far, and I would appreciate any input to resolve these issues.

### 1. Plots

Here is a plot I have tried and it works well:

```
Plot3D[EllipticTheta[3, Pi/2  x, t], {x, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I understand the peaks as the Theta function approaches a Dirac comb when t=1.

Then I try

```
Plot3D[EllipticTheta[3, Pi/2 x, E^(- Pi^2 t)],{x,0,2},{t,0,tmax}]
```

this is how it looks for `tmax=1`

[image]

by increasing `tmax` things start looking strange, and eventually the kernel seems to crash (from about `tmax=4.5`). This is how it looks for `tmax=5`

[image]

It becomes even worse for larger values of `tmax`. I don't seem to understand what is causing the problem, and how choosing larger intervals for the plot messes up the part of the plot for smaller values of `t` which were looking fine with `tmax=1`.

### 2. Derivatives

I have read that derivatives of the Theta function with respect to its third argument are problematic as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80447/imaginary-terms-in-the-derivative-of-jacobi-theta-function-2-on-the-real-line), but I do not understand the reason. The solution suggested in that post is to use the corresponding PDE, i.e.

```
Derivative[0,0,1][EllipticTheta][3,Pi/2 x,E^(-Pi^2 t)] = 
Derivative[0,2,0][EllipticTheta][3,Pi/2 x,E^(-Pi^2 t)]
```

So this means instead of `Derivative[0,1,1][EllipticTheta][3,Pi/2 x,E^(-Pi^2 t)]` it's better to use `Derivative[0,3,0][EllipticTheta][3,Pi/2 x,E^(-Pi^2 t)]`. To check, I plot it

```
Plot3D[ Evaluate[
  Derivative[0, 3, 0][EllipticTheta][3, Pi/2 x, E^(-Pi^2 t)]], {x, 0, 
  2}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that this is quite slow to generate.
**Q: How to improve the speed?**

In addition, I do not know if the values of these higher-order derivatives  are something that I could trust.

Also, when I try increasing t to, say,  `{t,0,2}` Mathematica v12.1 jumps out of the notebook. Note that I am actually trying to use these derivatives as part of an integrand (like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226121/difficult-numerical-integral-with-special-functions/226355?noredirect=1#comment576484_226355)) and I'd want to avoid singularities/numerical instabilities even in the cost of (a bit of) accuracy. So maybe I should use a finite sum, instead of the infinite sum in the definition of `EllipticTheta`?

Here is another example, which (I think) should be identical to zero (adapted from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65133/how-to-define-a-function-that-is-related-to-derivative-of-jacobi-theta-function))

```
Plot[ Evaluate[ 
  D[EllipticTheta[3, x, E^(-Pi^2 t)], {x, 3}] /. x -> 0], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

(**edit/update:** flinty's solution to define a WorkingPrecision resolves this latter one. I had assumed Mathematica does not need that for built-in functions)

### Question

Is there a better way to deal with EllipticTheta in Mathematica? I tried implementing it as the direct summation it is defined through, and ran exactly to the same problems. So I guess Mathematica might be actually evaluating the sum when EllipticTheta is called, and maybe that is causing the problems (since it'll run into exponentials with very large negative powers).

Comment: The problem where it starts looking weird for tmax=5 is because the automatic plot range for the z-axis is a very narrow slice around 1.0 , too narrow for rendering precision. A similar issue occurs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225076/graphics-glitch-or-modern-art) and it's resolved by choosing a wider `PlotRange` .

Comment: @flinty Thank you, I didn't know that. It does seem to partially resolve the issue when I choose ```PlotRange->{-2,2}``` for  tmax=5, but close to t=0 there is a strange behaviour which seems to be different than the same region for tmax=1.

Comment: Try `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", MaxRecursion -> 6` - it might smooth it out.

Comment: For the part on the derivative, this is just an artifact of `$MachinePrecision` calculations. Try using `WorkingPrecision -> 10` or `20` in the plot options and it's no longer a problem.

Comment: @flinty thank you for the comments. They did resolve the plotting issues. However, I have had a lot of difficulties with the derivatives of EllipticTheta (especially taking derivatives wrt the third argument, or taking derivatives higher than 2 from the second argument) - so I was hoping there is a better way of handling them.